# Best JavaScript pattern for jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

We have been using jasmine for a while now. We have written specs for about 20% code. Most of our code is tightly coupled with DOM elements which makes it extremely difficult to test. Now we would like to re-factor our code and make it testable with jasmine.

So my question is: **Which JavaScript pattern has got an edge in terms of testing (jasmine) ease and why?**

Update: I did some research and found couple of useful tips:

- Private Methods and Properties are difficult to test, so avoid if testing is preference.
- JQuery Chaining: Again chaining is recommended for performance but excessive use will not be recommended for unit test.